# Python selenium webdriver: list index out of range

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have following code to scroll down a javascript enabled website. Problem is when the `newHeight` reaches around `229275` I get list out of range on the line              `browser.find_elements_by_class_name('alt')[0].click()`. But why I am getting this error and how can I solve this?

My code:

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS("phantomjs")
    browser.get(url)
        while True:            
         time.sleep(pause)
         newHeight = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
         print newHeight
         browser.find_elements_by_class_name('alt')[0].click()
```

Comment: The element doesn't exist in the page at the time `find_elements_by_class_name` is called. It's either no longer present or not yet present. Try to wait for it or handle the case where it's no longer present.

Answer (score 1):

Try to scroll down page and click element with below approach:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS("phantomjs")
browser.get(url)
while True:
    browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.END)
    try:
        wait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "alt"))).click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

This should allow you to click required element in case it can be found or break loop otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Simply try/except statement

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS("phantomjs")
browser.get(url)
    while True:   
     try:
        time.sleep(pause)
        newHeight = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        print newHeight
        browser.find_elements_by_class_name('alt')[0].click()
     except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the list before acting upon it.

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS("phantomjs")
browser.get(url)
while True:            
    time.sleep(pause)
    newHeight = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    print newHeight
    alt_elements = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('alt')
    if len(alt_elements):
        alt_elements[0].click()
```

Just a side note, an infinite while loop can be a dangerous thing.